# Power BI How to calculate average/stdev of slicer selected items within Date Range?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Power BI table looks like this:

```
Cat sales   Date
apple   2.0 03/18/2021
apple   1.8 03/19/2021
apple   2.0 03/20/2021
apple   2.5 03/21/2021
peach   3.1 03/18/2021
peach   3.0 03/19/2021
peach   1.7 03/20/2021
peach   2.0 03/21/2021
pear    4.2 03/18/2021
pear    4.4 03/19/2021
pear    3.9 03/20/2021
pear    4.9 03/21/2021
```

I want to use a date slicer and Cat filter to calculate the (average sales)/(standard deviation of sales) during a period and display in a tile:

For example:
Slicer select:  Apple and Pear
Date Slicer: 03/18/2021 - 03/20/2021
[image]

Formula:

```
Step 1:   Average = (6.2 + 6.2 + 5.9) = 6.1
03/18/2021   2+4.2= 6.2
03/19/2021   1.8+4.4 = 6.2
03/20/2021   2+3.9 = 5.9

Step 2:   Stdev(6.2,6.2,5.9) = 0.1732

Step 3:   Average/Stdev = 6.1/0.1732 = 35.22
```

Tile display: 35.22

I am new to DAX and wasn't able to figure out the right formula, Please help!

Comment: Sorry, what is the question? If you have a measure showing in a card, and you have slicers that apply to the card, then the value showing in the card will be factoring in the slicers. So just create your measure(s) and use them in visuals, then apply slicers.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to create separate Average or STDEV, but how can I make them divide? sorry i am new to power BI

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself (correct me if i am wrong) and posted here if it ever be useful for other people;

```
Ratio = 
AVERAGEX(
    KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Data_table'[Sales])),
    CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Data_table'[Sales]))
)/ 
STDEVX.P(
    KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Data_table'[Sales])),
    CALCULATE(SUM('Data_table'[Sales]))
)
```

Comment: As I said above: you don't need to work the slicers into the measures if you just want to show them in visuals. That's what Power BI is all about: the cross-filtering of visuals on a page. If you select a slicer, all connected visuals will react, You don't have to calculate a measure that explicityly keeps the filters of the slicer.